# Como fazer um botão de transição semelhante ao do Google Tradutor para uma operação matemática

Tags: javascript, html, matemática

Estou a criar uma pequena calculadora que converte **Quilogramas** em **Pounds**
e **Pounds** em **Quilogramas**.

O meu objetivo é inserir um valor num primeiro `input` e exibir o resultado num segundo `input` que vem em seguida. Por exemplo:

```
<input id='in' value='1' type='text'/>             <!-- O usuário insere 1KG no primeiro input para converter em Pounds -->
<input id='out' value='2.20462262' type='text'/>   <!-- E o resultado aparecerá aqui no seguindo input: 2.20462262 -->
```

O conceito base é este! Mas agora eu queria que existisse um botão tipo o do Google Tradutor no meio destes dois `inputs`, no qual invertesse as unidades de cálculo, ou seja no início estaríamos a calcular - (`KG para Pounds`), clicando no botão inverterá as unidades de cálculo/peso e agora estaremos a calcular - (`Pounds para KG`). Tudo isto num só botão.

Melhor explicando. No início estaríamos a calcular quantos quilos seria um valor `X` em Pounds:

```css
.caixa {display: inline-block;}
```

```html
<div class="caixa">
    Quilogramas<br />
    <input id='field1' value='50' type='text'/>
</div>
<div class="caixa"><button id='switch'>Inverter Unidade</button></div>
<div class="caixa">
    Pounds<br />
    <input id='field2' value='110.23' type='text'/>
</div>
```

Clicando no botão `Inverter Unidade`, ele inverte as unidades de peso podendo agora calcular quantas `Pounds` será um valor `X` em `Quilogramas`:

```css
.caixa {display: inline-block;}
```

```html
<div class="caixa">
    Pounds<br />
    <input id='field1' value='100' type='text'/>
</div>
<div class="caixa"><button id='switch'>Inverter Unidade</button></div>
<div class="caixa">
    Quilogramas<br />
    <input id='field2' value='45.35' type='text'/>
</div>
```

Deu para entender aquilo que eu quero fazer? Eis o código daquilo que eu tenho até agora:

```
function calcPD(){
    var pound = document.getElementById("field1").value;
    var calc = quilos / 2.2046;
    var resul = document.getElementById("field2").value=calcular.toFixed(2);    
}

function calcKg(){      
    var kg = document.getElementById("field1").value;
    var calc = quilo * 2.2046;
    var resul = document.getElementById("field2").value=calcular.toFixed(2);                            
}
```

Comment: Tipo [**isso**](http://jsfiddle.net/owkLs70t/)?

Comment: Eu entendi oque ele está querendo e já desenvolvi uma solução.

Comment: @devgaspa tem como postar a solução?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caro,

Desenvolvi uma solução para a sua necessidade, qualquer dúvida é só comentar, porém o código está bem elegível. Tem aqui também um exemplo no [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/devgaspa/uh6mvsLt/) se preferir.

```js
var conversor = {
    // Valores do Objeto conversor
    valor : document.getElementById('iptValor'),
    resultado : document.getElementById('iptResultado'),
    labelValor : document.getElementById('lblValor'),
    labelResultado : document.getElementById('lblResultado'),
    unidade : 2.2046,
    operacao : 'Kilos',
    // Valores Funções do Objeto conversor
    Kilos : function() {
      return this.valor.value * this.unidade;
    },
    Pounds : function() {
      return this.valor.value / this.unidade;
    },
    trocar : function() {
      this.labelResultado.innerText = this.operacao;
      this.operacao = this.operacao === 'Kilos' ? 'Pounds' : 'Kilos';
      this.labelValor.innerText = this.operacao;
      this.calcular(this.valor.value);
    },
    // Função para conversão.
    calcular : function() {
      if(this.valor.value != '')
       this.resultado.value = conversor[this.operacao]().toFixed(4); // .toFixed(4) fixa 4 casas decimais.
    }
}

// Adiciona o evento click ao botão trocar
document.getElementById('trocar').addEventListener('click', function() {
 conversor.trocar(); // Chama a função que troca a conversão
}, false);
// Adiciona o evento click ao botão calcular
document.getElementById('calcular').addEventListener('click', function() {
 conversor.calcular(); // Chama a função que calcula a conversão
}, false);
```

```html
<div>
    <!-- Label + Input referente ao valor base da conversão -->
    <label id="lblValor" for="iptValor">Kilos</label>
    <input type="number" id="iptValor">
    <!-- Neste botão será adiciona um evento de click -->
    <button id="trocar">Trocar</button>
    <!-- Label + Input referente ao resultado da conversão -->
    <label id="lblResultado" for="iptResultado">Pounds</label>
    <input type="number" id="iptResultado">
    <!-- Neste botão será adiciona um evento de click -->
    <button id="calcular">Calcular</button>
</div>
```

Comment: olá, sua resposta depende totalmente de um recurso externo, é [recomendado fornecer um contexto](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) ao utilizar links desse tipo, além disso o SO suporta códigos javascript executáveis, para inserir utilize `Ctrl` + `M` no editor

Comment: @Sanção Obrigado :)

Comment: Olá @devgaspa! É exatamente disso que estou precisando para terminar meu código. Muito obrigado pela contribuição. Porém... Ao copiar o código e rodar na minha máquina, o mesmo apresenta um erro referente ao evento "addEventListener". Não é possível ler tal propriedade, a mesma está NULL. O que pode ser? (tenho certeza que é besteira, mas ainda não sei como resolver).

Comment: @LuizSantos provavelmente não está encontrando o elemento para adicionar o evento ou está tentando adicionar em um elemento inválido para atribuição. coloque seu código aqui ou em um jsfiddle para eu analisar.

Comment: Esse é o problema @devgaspa. Eu estou apenas copiando e colando seu código numa página limpa. Só para rodar mesmo localmente e nada.

Comment: @LuizSantos Você alterou o HTML ?

Comment: @devgaspa Não. Apenas copiei e colei tudo.

Comment: @LuizSantos você está declarando o script por último dentro da tag `<body>`?

Comment: Não. Alterei, pegoou! Mais uma vez obrigado @devgaspa!! Mas, por que isso? Sei que a linguagem JS é interpretada.. Tem algo a ver?

Comment: @LuizSantos Tem a ver sim, isso ocorreu porque antes de renderizar os elementos dentro da tag `<body>` ele interpretou o javascript e como a adição dos eventos nos elementos está feita de uma forma não elaborada o javascript tentou adicionar os eventos em elementos que não existiam até então. para que isso não ocorra é necessário criar um evento, por exemplo, `window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fn, false)` para que execute o código somente após a página carregada.

Comment: @devgaspa entendi. Obrigado pela ajuda!!